# How to encrypt cart data send to paypal

Tags: encryption, paypal

i have a cart and when user purchase and check out then some data send to paypal. i have checked that using firebug we can see what data has been posted to paypal site. like sample data posted to paypal below

```
address1    Unit 1 Stirling Park
address_override    1
amount_1    350.00
amount_2    11.00
amount_3    72.20
business    msindia@bba-reman.com
cancel_return   http://www.msindia.com/catalogue/order/PayPalFailure.aspx
city    Rochester
cmd _cart
cn  How did you hear about us?
country GB
currency_code   GBP
first_name  ben
invoice PP001250
item_name_1 Marea 2.4 TD
item_name_2 carriage
item_name_3 VAT Amount
item_number_1   0281001741
last_name   walker
notify_url  http://www.msindia.com/catalogue/order/PayPalNotify.aspx
return  http://www.msindia.com/catalogue/order/PayPalSuccess.aspx
state   KENT
upload  1
zip ME9 3QQ
```

is there any trick by which we can encrypt data and then send to paypal but paypal will understand that encryption and populate its form with incoming data. please guide if any one has prior experience. thanks

Comment: What is the url you are posting? Are you using PayPal Standard?